# Entity MetaData for Doctrine and multiple Entity Managers

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm trying to setup an `Sql Server` connection for Doctrine in Symfony2.However I can not figure out how to setup some Entity `Foo` to be managed by the new Entity Manager.
I have seen [this](https://techpunch.co.uk/development/using-multiple-databases-with-symfony2-and-doctrine2) post in regards to managing Entities with multiple Entity Managers, however I don't know how to use it with different Entity Managers like this. What metadata should I use so I can handle some of My entities with the new Entity Manager?

Comment: You don't tell entities which manager to use.  Rather you tell the managers which entities to manage.  Start here: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/multiple_entity_managers.html Then if you need more fine grain control then read here: http://symfony.com/doc/2.7/reference/configuration/doctrine.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put Foo entity to separate bundle i.e MyFooBundle (if you have single core/app bundle) and map the bundle to other entity manager.

Disable auto mapping and configure connections at config.yml then define the entity managers and mapping

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        connections:
            default:
                driver:   %database_driver%
                host:     %database_host%
                dbname:   %database_name%
                user:     %database_user%
                password: %database_password%
                charset:  UTF8
            other:
                driver:   %database_driver_2%
                host:     %database_host_2%
                dbname:   %database_name_2%
                user:     %database_user_2%
                password: %database_password_2%
                charset:  UTF8
    orm:
        entity_managers:
            default:
                connection: default
                mappings:
                   FOSUserBundle: ~
                   AppBundle: ~
            other:
               connection: other
               mappings:
                   MyFooBundle: ~
```

Comment: This works.( I didn't use it with the shorthand bundle syntax used here)